# Convert .so code from ARM to x86 on Android

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, x86, arm

I'm trying to convert the .so file generated by the NDK that has been compiled for an ARM Android device into an .so file for an x86 device.

I can take the .so file and use objdump to read the assembly, but objdump doesn't really put it into a format that I can just recompile it-- so it seems easier to just convert the Machine Code instructions One-To-One.

Any ideas? I'm hoping to convert ARM libraries to x86 so native code ARM apps from the NDK will run better on my x86 Android VMWare.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible (although there have been designs like the Transmeta chips, so ..). It's not really a [trivial] "One-To-One" operation as many aspects differ - although there might be advanced transpiler (applies to machine code?) tools, I wouldn't spend much time exploring this route.

Comment: Can't you ask the person who released the ARM version of the library for an x86 version? (I'm assuming that it's closed source, since otherwise you could just build it yourself)

Comment: One way to do this is to run a [tag:decompiler] and then use an **x86** compiler on the output.  It is not simple.  This will generate better code than direct translation.  First off, the ARM has 16 registers, so you have difficulty emulating that on the **x86**.  The **decompiled** output will allow an **x86** compiler to intelligently allocate registers versus frame variables.  There are many questions like this on Stack Overflow.  Examining the *assembler* and reverse engineering the routine flow is also possible if the code size is small; [tag:decompiling] the code will help here.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is binary translation.  You can read about [Intel's solution](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5770/lava-xolo-x900-review-the-first-intel-medfield-phone/3) for their x86-based mobile devices.

This is not an easy thing to solve generally.  You could try to adapt [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)'s engine, which converts binaries to an intermediate format and then generates native code from it, but if you've used the Android emulator you know that the performance of this solution can be poor.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use the below steps to recompile,

1. add APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 in Android makefile and rebuild the project
2. On command prompt(if no makefile is found) use the following command
           ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a x86“
3. Package the application again for x86 platforms